# Is it possible to partially extract a zipped file?

Tags: zip, archiving, extract

Is it possible to extract only part of a file from a `.zip` archive?

The file is plain text, and it is much bigger than available disk space. Is it possible to extract it in parts?

Comment: Extract to `stdout` (`unzip -p` on Linux), pipe through some other tool that extracts part of it (e.g. `dd` on Linux).

Comment: Ditto. Note `dd` operates on bytes and therefore it can split a text stream mid-line or even mid-character (for multibyte characters). A reasonable approach is to work with lines (e.g. `tail -n +21 | head -n 10`; or `sed -n '21,30 p; 30 q'`, or some equivalent `awk` code). Extremely long lines may be rejected or mishandled, or they may make the size of the output exceed your expectations. Note a file with lines exceeding `{LINE_MAX}` bytes in length is not a text file in formal terms of POSIX. When you say "plain text", does it mean the lines are reasonably short for sure?

Comment: Similar question on Unix & Linux: [How to partially extract zipped huge plain text file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/415799/how-to-partially-extract-zipped-huge-plain-text-file)